# How to set default system file encoding in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: file, intellij-idea, file-encodings

I want IDEA to use whatever default system encoding is, instead it uses whatever is set through Settings > File Encodings. Which is set to UTF-8.

My application runs fine in Eclipse, which uses default system encoding on windows, but it is having trouble reading some xmi files when running the application through IDEA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can select system's default encoding from the same drop down:

[image]

Comment: In version 2023.3, it can be found in Settings -> Editor -> File Encodings

Answer (score 3):

Found it in File->Other Settings->Default encoding: http://ufasoli.blogspot.ru/2013/10/intellij-change-default-encoding-for.html